# how to use linux backtrace and backtrace_symbols API to find thread causing segmentation fault

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, backtrace, stack-dump

Hello my fellow Developers,

I am trying to analyse stack-dump from a C++ program, in this particular program we are creating signal handlers and and inside signal handler we have code something like below

```
res = backtrace(arr, size);
if (res > 0)
{
  btrace = backtrace_symbols(arr, size);
}
for ( unsigned int i =0; i < size ; ++i )
{
    log_error(" trace: %s", btrace[i] );
}
```

I am able to get traces however unable to find address which i am expecting, now I am wondering if **there is any possibility that other threads might have filled the stacktrace buffer**(as it is an embedded device and we have limited buffer size), if so **how i can identify/filter stacktraces thread wise or is there any option to restrict stacktraces to only thread which caught segmentation fault.**

**Note:** I am able to identify 2 addresses from my executable which are present in stacktrace, very recent one is the address of signal handler itself and 2nd one is from another thread.

I tried to googling resources on how backtrace works in multi threaded env. on but not able to find much info, so I am here.

Thanks

Comment: Is `backtrace()` a user-defined function?

Comment: @kiner_shah no, it's glibc

Comment: Please note that `backtrace_symbols` are not async symbol safe in practice (technically, neither of backtrace symbols are async signal safe, but in practice, `backtrace` is OK to call in signal handler)

Comment: Generally speaking, `backtrace` works well in multi-threaded environment, and multithreading by itself should not be a problem. Please note, in optimized code your traces my look weird. I would suggest trying attaching a debugger and looking at the trace on the live app.

Comment: thanks @SergeyA for clarification usage of `backtrace_symbols`  and `backtrace`, but unfortunately running trace in live app is not an possibility here, btw what exactly do you mean by " your traces may look weird" is it regarding order of appearance of addresses in trace or something related to optimized code ?